# Unable to click addon on Firefox

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, firefox-addon

[image]

[image]

I have a scenario where i go to simple-modify-header addon and then click on configure button.
In windows os everything is working fine, but in Linux I am not able to get the pop-up displayed, after I click on addon.

The following code is used to navigate to addon

```
           //move to toolbar
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_L);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    //move to addons
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    //move to simple-modify-header addon
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
    Thread.sleep(2000);


    //click simple-modify-header addon
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.delay(2000);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    Thread.sleep(1000);

//click on configure addon
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.delay(2000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.delay(1000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
```

Comment: can you share some HTML, and code attempts and in linux is not getting displayed so screens hot of that would be helpful

Comment: This pop-up is not part of the web page. I click it from firefox toolbar and then hit enter using Robot class. I don't know why I can not perform any action from toolbar on Firefox browser in Linux.

Comment: How are you clicking on windows  ?I know you are using robot class, but I'd like to know how ?

Comment: I updated the question and added the code used to click the addon. As I said this works fine on Windows.